# Backbone Collection add strange behavior in Firefox

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Faced with such a strange problem with Backbone collection.
I tried to add new elements in these way:

```
sortCollection.add([
        {id: "recommended", title: 'Recommend movies'},
        {id: "popular",     title: 'Popular movies'},
        {id: "watch",       title: 'Watching now'},
        {id: "add",         title: 'Last Editions'}
    ]);
```

But, when I tried to render it one item with id="watch" always disappeared. Furthermore, if I do console.log(sortCollection.length) there is only 3 items.

JSFiddle with my code is here - [JsFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zyyC7/3/)

Thanks to @doctororange:

> This issue seems to have been uncovered and solved very recently: [github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2719](http://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2719)

Problem solved.

Comment: I'm seeing all four items rendered in your JsFiddle. Do you?

Comment: the problem is with id: watch, but i dont know the reason

Comment: is it necessary to stick to this id?

Comment: "is it necessary to stick to this id? " - it's desirable

"the problem is with id: watch, but i dont know the reason" - it's become the question of interest. WHY ? Really Why?

Comment: You can reduce your problem to http://jsfiddle.net/KDYck/ Very weird.

Comment: And that works on Chrome and IE, `watch` only disappears with Firefox

Comment: @nikoshr - really) I didn't mention before.

Comment: This issue seems to have been uncovered and solved very recently: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2719

Comment: @LadyBo I added my comment as an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to have been uncovered and solved very recently

https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2719